# How do I render the comment form?

Tags: 8, comments

I have attached a comment type to a content type via a field.  Right now all I can see is a link called ***Add new comment***. How do get the comment form to render on the node and not show the link?

Comment: What is a `comment type`? How did you make such attachment? programatically or ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've assumed your question correctly, you want to show the comment form when displaying the node content page. You can do this by enabling a setting "**Show reply form on the same page as comments**" in Comment field. Check screenshot below:

1. Edit Comment field

[image: Manage Fields Page]

2. Enable "**Show reply form on the same page as comments**" setting checkbox and click on "**Save Settings**".

[image: Edit Comment Field Page]